# How to call a node file from elixir backend file

Tags: elixir

I am trying to access node file from elixir but i do not know how to it?
I googled a lot but could not get any clue to achieve this. Please help me.

Comment: What is _“node file”_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can call the node file from the elixir .ex file using system commands, as you can see in below mentioned code , there are two parameter it accept

1. First parameter is type of file which you need to access like : "node"
2. Second it accept the other parameter that you will access in your in your node file
   a: First parameter should always be the path of the file that you need to call
   b:  Rest other are optional depends upon your requirement

After Calling the "system.cmd" if in case any error comes in your calling file like : "node" then you will receive a tuple of error which would have the value other than 0 and if your file executes successfully then you will receive in return {"",0}, on this basis you can assume your execution result

Please use the below code use and please comment below so i could solve try to solve your question , hope this will resolve your question.

```
 with {_, 0} <-
           System.cmd("node", [
             "Path of node file",
              "input parameter" 
              "input parameter"  
           ]) do
      {:ok, "success"}
    else
      _ ->
        {:error, "Error in node file"}
    end
```

Comment: Using `with` with one omnivorous `else` clause is an antipattern, one should use `case` instead.

Comment: Also, once the called command would spit _anything_ to stdout, this would fail with `{:error, _}`. I doubt this is anyhow usable answer.

Comment: I am already have implement in the same way and it working perfectly, system.cmd itself return tuple and it is running perfectly without any error and one thing more suggestion was only for the system command not for with it choice for the questionnaire he can go with any  approach.

Comment: if you have any better approach for how can we call node file from elixir file so please feel free to post, will be added plus in experience.

Comment: Try to call `System.cmd("ls", [])` and see it goes through the wrong clause. Match in the very first line should be at least `{_, 0}` instead of strict `{"", 0}` rejecting anything with standard output from the running command.

Comment: Every time will expect exactly the same tuple so thats why i have made it like this, just because for no other surprises in the output , yes i know _ make it pass with anything comes with 0. it basically depend up questionnaire what exactly he is getting in the ourput. thanks